# error when trying to create new menu item / Joomla! 3.8.10

Tags: joomla

I hope somebody can help me .. I try to open a new entry in a joomla menu and get the following error output:

0 Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
/mnt/web208/e2/01/56797301/htdocs/plugins/system/helix3/helix3.php:55

[error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOPOc.jpg)

> ## Function    Location 1  ()  JROOT/plugins/system/helix3/helix3.php:55 2 plgSystemHelix3->onContentPrepareForm() JROOT/libraries/joomla/event/event.php:70
>
> 3 JEvent->update()    JROOT/libraries/joomla/event/dispatcher.php:160
>   4 JEventDispatcher->trigger() JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Model/FormModel.php:321
>   5 Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\FormModel->preprocessForm()    JROOT/administrator/components/com_menus/models/item.php:1254
>   6 MenusModelItem->preprocessForm()    JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Model/FormModel.php:242
>   7 Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\FormModel->loadForm()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_menus/models/item.php:552
>   8 MenusModelItem->getForm()   JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/View/HtmlView.php:423
>   9 Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\HtmlView->get() JROOT/administrator/components/com_menus/views/item/view.html.php:58
>   10    MenusViewItem->display()    JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:672
>   11    Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->display() JROOT/administrator/components/com_menus/controller.php:75 12   MenusController->display()  JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:710
>   13    Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute() JROOT/administrator/components/com_menus/menus.php:18
>   14    require_once()  JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:382
>   15    Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent()    JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:357
>   16    Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent() JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:101
>   17    Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch() JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:159
>   18    Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()    JROOT/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:195
>   19    Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()    JROOT/administrator/index.php:51

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange. Please ask all Joomla questions at JSE.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred in the file helix3.php on line 55. Plugging the displayed notation ("helix3.php:55", with the quotes) into Google yields this page as first result:

https://www.joomshaper.com/forums/helix3-plugins-causing-joomal-menu-to-not-work-0-cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array

This site states it's a known bug and an update will be released soon. Try to update the plugin, or modify the helix3.php file as explained.

And please use Google (or another search engine of your liking) before posting a question. Filenames + Line numbers as well as paths and the first sentence of error messages make for great search terms.

PS: Welcome on StackOverflow!

Comment: If you are able to provide Joomla support, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.